# Securing a REST Api with Spring Security

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security and I'm trying to secure a REST api inside my app. I have the app URIS and then I have an URI like "/api/v1/" to my rest api.

I have secured my application with username/password authentication and it's working fine, but now I want to secure my REST api returning 401 Unauthorized if the user isn't authenticated, but I don't know how to keep the two authentications together.

What it's the way to go here?

PS: I'm using Spring MVC with Spring Security

This is my Spring Security configuration right now:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me-key", accountService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.eraseCredentials(true).userDetailsService(accountService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/signup").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/signin").permitAll().failureUrl("/signin?error=1")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/signin?logout")
                .and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).key("remember-me-key")
                .and().csrf();
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have form login plus secure rest api right?

[jhipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) can generate such project structure. Let me give some example code for achieving this if you don't want to use jhipster (it's pretty cool though, I recommend)

to return 401 for unauthorized you need something like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a 401 error code (Unauthorized) to the client.
 */
@Component
public class Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint.class);

    /**
     * Always returns a 401 error code to the client.
     */
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException arg2)
        throws IOException,
        ServletException {

        log.debug("Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access Denied");
    }
}
```

then inject and add this to your SecurityConfig.configure(HttpSecurity http) method:

```
http.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
```

plus since REST requests are ajax requests you also need ajax entry points:

```
/**
 * Returns a 401 error code (Unauthorized) to the client, when Ajax authentication fails.
 */
@Component
public class AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication failed");
    }
}


/**
 * Spring Security success handler, specialized for Ajax requests.
 */
@Component
public class AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}

/**
 * Spring Security logout handler, specialized for Ajax requests.
 */
@Component
public class AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler
    implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

add them to security config too:

```
http.successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
    .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
    .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
```

All credit goes to the amazing jhipster authors.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good approach to what I want, but finally I did it like this, a more elegant and simple solution: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

Answer (score -2):

You can use expression based access control 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Something like,

```
<intercept-url pattern=/** access="isFullyAuthenticated()/>
```

Comment: And how can I return a 401 Unauthorized using that?